# ASP .net core app not working when i deploy to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

https://github.com/viktor111/ASP.net-Core-Blog

This i my app i try to deploy. I tried 2 ways with github and from VS but when i get the link to the app its white there are no views no routing no errors just nothing. Also the favicon seems to work at top si i dont know where the problem is. I also tried creating new app to deploy and it works but the one i have worked on for a whilne dosent i tried moving the project to diffrent directory and deplying again and still not working.

Comment: Hi @Aniki. Are you deploying to an App Service? If yes, what does the Stack and Platform configuration look like under `Configuration -> General Settings`?

Comment: Have you set up your application configuration in Azure after deployment?

Comment: You can also see IIS or Server level error using Kudu tool.

Comment: Hello @devlife. Platform is 32bit option and stack is .NET option.

Comment: I tried now nut i get  this error "ANCM Failed to Load dll"

Comment: Ok that's good! That is progress. Is your application built for 32 bit or 64 bit? Take a look at this link to enable asp.net core logging https://stackify.com/net-core-azure-app-service-wont-start/ and this one for how to view the logs https://www.gslab.com/blogs/kudu-azure-web-app

Comment: Any update on this issue?